# Arranging objects in random rows and columns

Tags: c#, list, random

```
    private void InitialSetup()
    {
        AddPiece(whiteRook, white, 0, 0);
        AddPiece(whiteKnight, white,1,2);
        AddPiece(whiteBishop, white,2,0);
        AddPiece(whiteQueen, white, 3,4);
        AddPiece(whiteKing, white, 4, 6);
        AddPiece(whiteBishop, white,5,0);
        AddPiece(whiteKnight, white,6,3);
        AddPiece(whiteRook, white, 7, 6);
    }
 
    public void AddPiece(GameObject prefab, Player player, int col, int row)
    {
        GameObject pieceObject = board.AddPiece(prefab, col, row);

        player.pieces.Add(pieceObject);
        pieces[col, row] = pieceObject;
    }
```

8 columns 6 rows

I have 48 game objects, I want them to be arranged in random rows and columns every time the game starts, but how can I do this with the addPiece method?

Answer (score 1):

Use following :

```
           Random rand = new Random();
            //create an array from 0 to 47 with each number occurring once
            int[] randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 48)
                .Select(x => new { x = x, rand = rand.Next() })
                .OrderBy(x => x.rand)
                .Select(x=> x.x)
                .ToArray();
            int[,] matrix = new int[6,8];
            for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
            {
                //rows and columns start at index zero
                int row = randomNumbers[i] / 8;
                int col = randomNumbers[i] % 8;
                matrix[row, col] = i;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do not understand how to use what you wrote with add Piece method

Comment: I didn't write the add piece method.  I only wrote code to add random number to a matrix as an example. I updated code which takes the numbers 0 to 47 and put into a randomly into an array.  The first index of randomNumber contains 30.  It means the first piece will go into row 3 (30/8) and into column 6 (30 % 8) where row and column start at zero.

Comment: ok thanks a lot .. i need to work more for the method

Comment: You are passing a row and column to method so my code will be used before you call the method to get the row and column.